# C++ Templates with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors

I have recently started macros and templates. I made an application using template where you enter two integer with different data types and it tells you which one is bigger. But every time I execute the code it gives me this error

> Error 1   error C2371: 'comp' : redefinition; different basic types
>   line:36 Column:1

and here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename B>
class Compare{
public:
    Compare(const T& hAge1, const B& hAge2){
        age1 = hAge1;
        age2 = hAge2;
    }
    void display_result(){
        if (age1 > age2){
            cout << "Your age is bigger" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Your age is smaller" << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    T age1;
    B age2;
};

int main(){
    int your_age;
    int someother_age;
    //user interface
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> your_age;
    cout << "Enter some other age: ";
    cin >> someother_age;
    /*create instance of class Comepare*/
    Compare<int,double>comp(your_age, someother_age);
    comp.display_result();
    //create another instance 
    Compare<int, int>comp(your_age, someother_age);
    comp.display_result();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example could be reduced to `int main() {int a; double a;}` or similar. It's the same problem, and that's a compile-time error, not a runtime error.

Comment: Your compiler tells you exactly what the problem is. It even tells you on which line and which symbol is redefined. And to make easier, the first definition, is just a few line above. **It cannot be simpler that that.**

Answer (score 2):

You are just declaring two objects with the same name in one scope. Whether these are templates are not is entirely irrelevant. You might want to put the variables and their used in a dedicated block, e.g.

```
{
    /*create instance of class Comepare*/
    Compare<int,double>comp(your_age, someother_age);
    comp.display_result();
}
{
    //create another instance 
    Compare<int, int>comp(your_age, someother_age);
    comp.display_result();
}
```

Of course,  you could also just name your objects differently rather than reusing the name `comp` which isn't too descriptive anyway (compute, compare, compatible, comp...).

Comment: When I rename the second compare instance with different object i.e 'com'. It does work but it also displays the output of the first Compare instance 'comp' and the output of second 'com'

Comment: @jim And what you expect? The code do exactly what you told it to do? **And obviously, in your case, the answer would be the same if you use ints or doubles.**